# When going through Laracast Tutorials, the output I get doesn't match what they get. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm going through laracasts tutorials but my tinker does not look anything like laracasts and won't do what I'm trying to get it to do

```
    Psy Shell v0.5.1 (PHP 5.5.12 ÔÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $article = App\Article::create{['title' => 'New Article', 'body' => 'New body', 'published_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 1
>>> $article = App\Article::create{['title' => 'New Article', 'body' => 'New body', 'published_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()]);
PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 1
>>> $name
PHP error:  Undefined variable: name on line 1
>>> $article = new App\Article;
=> App\Article {#655}
>>> $article
=> App\Article {#655}
>>> new App\User;
=> App\User {#648}
>>> $article = new App\Article;
=> App\Article {#651}
>>>
```

This is what it's displaying does anyone know what could be wrong?

edit: new error that won't let me continue

```
    $article->save();
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: articles (SQL: insert into "articles" ("body", "published_at", "title", "updated_at", "created_at") v
    alues (Lorem ipsum, 2015-07-22 15:20:49, My First Article, 2015-07-22 15:27:15, 2015-07-22 15:27:15))'
```

edit2: Tried that article find line and it showed this

```
    Psy Shell v0.5.1 (PHP 5.5.12 ÔÇö cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $article = new App\Article;
=> App\Article {#652}
>>> $article - App\Article::find(1);
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: articles (SQL: select * from "articles" where "articles"."id" = 1 limit 1)'
```

The contents of my `config/database.php` file are:

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => 'sqlite',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => storage_path().'database.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],

];
```

Comment: Try instantiating an existing App\Article instance. The only thing that looks different is the {#655} numbers in your attribute printout. But they don't matter on empty model objects. $article = App\Article::find(1);
After you've created one.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have worked, I've put the error in my question

Comment: Looks like your table isn't set up. Did you set it up in sqlite or mysql? Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner.

Comment: Just set up the table again there following the previous video yet still when I type in $article = new App\Article; I just get back App\Article (#655). It's SQLite

Comment: But the error says the table doesn't exist. Have you configured your database connection in config/database.php?

Comment: Yeah just as he showed, I'll edit the post and show you my database file

Answer (score 1):

Your example comes from Windows Command Prompt.

You must remember, that Laravel was created in USA, where (almost) all tech people are Apple people. If you are not using Mac, you are not cool ;)

So lets forget Apple console and see it from Windows perspective.

```
>>> $article = new App\Article
=> App\Article {#658}
```

App\Article {#658} means that tinker prepped an empty object with #658 id attached to it.

Apple hatched Tinker, shows something like this:

```
>>$article;
object(App\Article) (
   'incrementing' => true,
   'timestamps' => true,
   'exists' => false
)
```

Command Prompt does not auto-populate object, it keeps it empty.

Probably reason is (but that is my guess only), that incrementing, timestamps are done automatically anyway, so why bother.

But these values, as shown by OSX Tinker, are there.

If you wish to see them, run in your Command Prompt tinker:

```
>>var_dump($article);
```

... but get ready for a lot of data thrown back at you.

If you inspect that data, you will find that missing object elements - as I did:

```
["incrementing"]=>bool(true)
["timestamps"]=>bool(true)
["exists"]=>bool(false)
```

So, missing object elements are there, they are not shown in Command Prompt hatched Tinker.

Now, you start populating your newly created object:

```
>>> $article->title = 'New Title';
=> "New Title"
>>> $article->body = 'Some body ... wow!';
=> "Some body ... wow!"
```

... you will see your object springing to life:

```
>>> $article
=> App\Article {#659
     title: "New Title",
     body: "Some body ... wow!",
   }
```

You can also see it as an array:

```
>>> $article->toArray();
=> [
     "title" => "New Title",
     "body" => "Some body ... wow!",
   ]
```

So, as you see, it is the same stuff, just in a different wrapper.

Thing is, when you learn, every little thing irritates and can throw you off the path. So, keep cool and keep at it - Laravel is well worth it.
Even if it just re-invents the same wheel ... for the nth time.
But it does it well.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the error you mentioned. The problem lies probably within the migration file. In both up() and down() methods you should use

Schema::create('articles' ...

and

Schema::drop('articles' ...

respectively. If you use 'article' instead, you run into the described error. Keep in mind that the table is for MANY articles, so it's name is 'articles', while the model describes ONE article - that's why it's name is 'article' - but it still reads/writes records from/to the 'articles' table. I hope it helps.